# Foreach into array

Tags: php, json

i have a JSON that i decode into array:

```
$json = '[{"CODICE":"A","COD. CRISI":1},{"CODICE":"25","COD. CRISI":1}]';

$arraydati = json_decode($json);
```

If i do `print_r($arraydati);`, i have this array:

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [CODICE] => A
            [COD. CRISI] => 1
        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [CODICE] => 25
            [COD. CRISI] => 1
        )


)
```

Now i want iterate the array and if "Codice" contains 25 i read the value.

I have a foreach loop

```
foreach($arraydati as $key=>$value){
    if($key['CODICE'] === '1'){
            echo($value['COD. CRISI']);
        }
    }
```

but non print nothing, where is the problem?

Comment: Hint: you've decoded the JSON as objects with properties, but you try to access them like arrays. I'm surprised you don't have any warnings or errors?

Comment: Did you check what `$key`  contains? Usually, that is an **array key**, and array keys itself cannot be arrays

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first loop result in an object, so you'll need `->`.

Also, `foreach` gives you the `$key` and `$value`, but  if you use `$key` you'll still need to target that key in `$arraydati`: `$arraydati[$key]`.

Much easier to use the `$value`!

```php
<?php

$json = '[{"CODICE":"A","COD. CRISI":1},{"CODICE":"25","COD. CRISI":1}]';

$arraydati = json_decode($json);

foreach ($arraydati as $value) {
    if ($value->CODICE === '25') {
        echo($value->{'COD. CRISI'});
    }
}
```

```
1
```

Comment: Thank you a lot, i'm new on php

Comment: and if i want to print the name of the value? in my case "COD.  CRISI"?